# Is there a time limit for retaining a request context?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a NodeJS application which uses socket.io to receive a stream of data.
The streaming time could go up to a maximum of 30 minutes. 
After the streaming is completed the socket is disconnected, and a chain of functions are invoked. These functions can also be very time-consuming.

Since this operates as a monolithic system, all these events are chained in one context. All the functions are asynchronous therefore it does not block the event loop.

Breaking up the functions into separate microservices would eliminate the need to retain the context for a long time.
But is there an industry standard time limit for how long an API server should maintain a request context? Or is the time not really an issue, if we have sufficient resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request context is just a Javascript object with a bunch of properties.  Hanging onto a reference to it for a longer period of time just means that the garbage collection for that object will be delayed.  The only real consequence of that is higher peak memory usage.

> But is there an industry standard time limit for how long an API server should maintain a request context?

There's no industry standard I'm aware of in this regard and I would think it's not really about standard ways of doing things as it is about how your own server works and is configured.  If you need to stream for 30 minutes (thus keeping the request open that long), then the request context is likely to be around that long.

> Or is the time not really an issue, if we have sufficient resources?

It's really just about resource usage.

---

You don't show us any of your code, but if you're done with the actual request object and just have other things to do that happen to be keeping the request object in scope, then you may be able to restructure your code a bit such that you can keep doing these other things you need to do (that don't access the request/response object) while allowing them to be garbage collected.